# Decompose in Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Can someone explain, why when we decompose function $a^{\frac{1}{x}} - a^{\frac{1}{x + 1}}$ in Taylor series, we got $\frac{ln(a)}{x^2}$ in first derivative?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I meant Taylor series

Comment: Let $p(x)=a^{\frac 1 x}$. Then $\ln p=\frac 1 x \ln a$

Comment: @tomi that is not Taylor series. I meant why when we decompose it in Taylor series, we got $\frac{ln(a)}{x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

My comment was intended as a hint to get you started.

Let $p(x)=a^{\frac 1x}$

Then $\ln p=\frac 1 x \ln a$

or $\ln p=x^{-1} \ln a$

Differentiating gives $\frac 1 p \dfrac {dp}{dx}=-x^{-2} \ln a$

So $\dfrac {dp}{dx}=-p \dfrac{\ln a}{x^2}=-a^{\frac 1x} \dfrac{\ln a}{x^2}$

Similarly if $q(x)=a^{\frac 1 {x+1}}$, then $\dfrac {dq}{dx}=-a^{\frac 1{x+1}} \dfrac{\ln a}{(x+1)^2}$

Your function is $a^{\frac 1 {x}}-a^{\frac 1 {x+1}}$.

Let's call this $f(x)$ and note that $f(x)=p(x)-q(x)$

$f'(x)=p'(x)-q'(x)=-a^{\frac 1x} \dfrac{\ln a}{x^2}+a^{\frac 1{x+1}} \dfrac{\ln a}{(x+1)^2}$